# Canon Printer Doesn't work Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, usb, printing

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu because it was running like a dog. When I installed the printer drivers, following these instructions, the printer wouldn't work. When I send a file nothing happens at the printer end. No response at all.

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/12/canon-driver-scangear-mp-ubuntu-14-04/

I thought I might have mucked something up, so I booted off the installation stick and installed the drivers and it worked.

So I reinstalled Ubuntu again but it still doesn't work! How can that be? How can it work from the flash stick and not from the hard drive??

Anyway, I followed the instructions here
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems

I would post the output but askubuntu thinks the output is spam, so what do I do?

Comment: Post the output at http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and [edit] into your post the link it will give you.

Answer (score 0):

Oh well, always the way. I think I've fixed it.
I got onto the cups interface via the web browser and started adding printers using different drivers. The cups-gutenprint driver for the mg6100 seems to work.

Thanks for listening.

Comment: No way, that cannot be the answer! I am having the same problem, but there has got to be a more systematic solution than that!